# How do you make Chromium use the VP9 codec with WebRTC?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, chromium, vp8, vp9

When using Chromium(48) or Chrome(45) for video chat the browsers appear to use the VP8 codec instead of VP9.  Searching the Chromium WebRTC source code shows many references to the VP9 codec so I believe that it is supported.

Based on Internet searches it looks like Chrome should use the VP9 codec with WebRTC when the "--enable-webrtc-vp9-support" flag is used but I have found that this flag does not appear to have any effect with Chrome *or* Chromium as the SDP still indicates that VP8 is being used.

Searching the Chromium source code does not return any matches on "enable-webrtc-vp9-support" either.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure you're on Dev or Canary Channel for that flag to work.  See the discussion on the [discuss-webrtc group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/i8kj9jr4yVo):

> It used to only be enabled for canary, have pushed it further to dev.
>   You may need to restart your chrome-dev once or twice before it makes effect.

Comment: I'm rebuilding Chromium from source, is there a different git repository for the "dev" version?

Comment: @ChrisM no, but that flag affects a config coming from somewhere else so you really have to be on dev/canary for it to take effect. Alternatively, since you're building from source, changing [this line](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libjingle/source/talk/media/webrtc/webrtcvideoengine2.cc&l=156) to `return true;` then recompiling should achieve the exact same thing.

Comment: @ChrisM Actually you might want to put `return true;` right under that `if (CodecNamesEq(codec_name, kVp9CodecName)) {` line. Note that this is only an acceptable solution for testing, you probably shouldn't distribute versions of Chromium with that modification :)